# Change colour of specifics excel cells using index numbers with Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am new in this community and really need some help.

I was wondering whether someone could help me with a small part of the code that I need to develop.

I have to highlight specifics cells in excel using Matlab. These cells are based on a condition that I have previously applied in my code and that will provide me a vector where the condition is not met and then I require to highlight in excel these cells using actxserver. I have been looking for other answers and I could not get info of how to do this. In VBA you can use Cells command to select specifics cell based on index and not range. It is working if I use range but in my case, the range will be changed depending on the work, so an index is the more appropriate. 
Example vector of 1X178 and I have found that values at 2 6 9 12 14 19 do not meet the condition, therefore, I would like to highlight in Excel. 
Thank you very much.

````m
vector_column=[2 6 9 12 14 19];
Excel=actxserver('excel.application') % Active server
WB=Excel.Workbooks.Open(fullfile('C:\Users\Cruz\Desktop\New folder','test_check2.xlsx'),0,false); % Open workbook
for j=1:size(vector_column,2)
 WB.Worksheets.Item(1).Cells(17,vector_column(j)).Interior.Color=hex2dec('00FF00');
 % Tried to change colour of excel cells at row 17 and columns number specify in the vector
end

WB.Save();
WB.Close();
Excel.Quit();```
````

Comment: Can you format your code correctly? Use ctrl+k on all instead of formatting every row separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `Range` if `Cells` method is not working. Juts modify your for loop like this:

```
for j=1:size(vector_column,2)
    column_letters=['A';'B';'C';'D';'E';'F';'G';'H';'I';'J';'K';'L';'M';'N';'O';'P';'Q';'R';'S'];
    WB.Worksheets.Item(1).Range(strcat(column_letters(j),num2str(17))).Interior.Color=hex2dec('00FF00');
end
```

This way you will have Range set to Row 17, with the column changing basing on your `vector_column`

For example `Range(strcat(column_letters(5),num2str(17)))` is an equivalent of `Range(strcat('E17')`